# Google Glass - adb get-serialno unknown

Tags: android, google-glass

Starting to test a multiplayer native Android game on multiple Glass devices... For most devices, adb install works well, as adb detects the device.

However, I also encounter the case where:

```
adb get-serialno
```

yields, instead of a serial number, the mysterious:

```
unknown
```

There was an old hack for fixing this for Gingerbread and lower, but Glass seems to be running a variant of ICS.

What is the recommended solution for getting adb to recognize Glass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mea culpa.

Apparently, debug mode was not turned on for the device whose serial showed up as unknown.